# Google maps как перехватить событие Блокировки определения местоположения пользователя?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Доброго времени уважаемые знатоки JS и google maps api. У меня следующая проблема. Как мне перехватить нажатие на кнопку Блокировать (см. картинку) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такая функция инициирует ее появление и устанавливает гео данные пользователя на сервер:

```
function initUserGeoData() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var lobj = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                mes: 'sendUserGeolocationOnServer',
                data: lobj
            },
            url: '/ajax/userLocation/userLocation.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (mes) {
                var responseObj = JSON.parse(mes);
                localStorage.setItem('userGeoData', JSON.stringify(responseObj));
                setUserCity();
            },
            error: function(e) {
                setDefaultCity();
            }
        });

    });
}else{
    console.log("error: Google map не подключена или исчерпан лимит запросов.");
    console.log("error: Установлен город по-умолчанию: Москва");
    setDefaultCity();
}
```

}

else в конце не отрабатывает. Есть ли какой то способ для перехвата отказа?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092400/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-geolocation-has-been-declined-with-javascript)  Оказывается вторым параметром можно переедать функцию для ошибки

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(position) {// ...},
    function(err){// ...});
```